# How to split data based on id?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading data from file so with below code pushing singular line data to `results` how can i split data based on id in below case `ID`. Goal is to get complete data for that id even its multiple lines.

Ctrl.js

```
  var results = [];
  var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
            lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                    results.push({
                    filename:logfile.filename,
                    value:line
                    });
                }
            });
```

file.txt

```
[ID:81d166ed-dcd6-4f30-bcf4-7c3c1a8feefb]testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting ind
[ID:8a3b2de6-742e-49e4-bf96-02d14e6b0799]testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry.
[ID:c3d19dfe-d803-4661-a0c4-52a18aa48766]testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy
```

Comment: what is `searchStr` value?

Comment: basically its a search feature so `searchStr` is user input from client and we have to match that data from file and send complete data of that event

Comment: unclear. *how can i split data based on id*. How should look the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If all your ID's are the same length, which it looks like they are, inside your lines.forEach you could put this to extract the ID.  Not sure entirely what you want to do with the rest of the line, but this looks like it'll grab the ID.

```
var id = line.substr(4,36)
```

Explanation, just grabbing the the text at that location in the string from the split, seems like it should always be in the same place.  There are more robust ways, but for this case it seems like an easily understood example.

Answer (score 0):

just add it before your foreach loop:

```
for(var i = 0; lines.length > i ; i = i + 1){
    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/\[ID:([a-z0-9]+-)+([a-z0-9])+\]/g, '');
}
```

it should results an array without your [ID: value], for your example it will return:

```
"testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting ind"
"testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy text text of the printing  and typesetting industry."
"testid Lorem test Ipsum is simply dummy"
```

Comment: thats not what i am trying to achieve here , I need to have IDs so i can make search based on those IDS